# How can I remove words with more than 3 consecutive letters?

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

currently I m working on a text mining(internet comment) case and I really want to remove those meaningless word. for example, aaaaawwwwww, weeeeeeeeeeeee etc.

I want to make a rule which can remove those words contain 3 or more consecutive letters.

can anyone help me to make this possible via `tm_map` or base on `DocumentTermMatrix` ?

this is what I have done so far

```
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, removePunctuation)
for (i in seq(tm_test)) {
  tm_test[[i]] = gsub("/", " ", tm_test[[i]])
  tm_test[[i]] = gsub("@", " ", tm_test[[i]])
  tm_test[[i]] = gsub("\\|", " ", tm_test[[i]])
} 
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, removeNumbers) 
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, tolower) 
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, PlainTextDocument) 
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, PlainTextDocument)
# tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, stemDocument)    
# tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, PlainTextDocument)
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, stripWhitespace)
tm_test = tm_map(tm_test, PlainTextDocument)
dtm_test = DocumentTermMatrix(tm_test)
```

simulated input data:

```
text = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'travelling', 'esteem', 'woooo','awwwwwwww','waaaaakakakakaka')
```

expected output:

```
out = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'tarvelling', 'esteem')
```

Comment: the original input data is way too big to check if it s the way I want.I will re-edit it and make up an input data. thanks man!

Comment: From the link : `gsub("\\S*(\\S)\\1\\1\\S*\\s?", "", "This is a bigggggg sentence toooo compleeeeete")`

Comment: @RonakShah thanks bro! that s exactly what I want!